# Generate Rspec test for existing Rails 3 Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've decided to learn Rspec, because I like its syntax better. So I've included the `rspec-rails` gem and ran `rails g rspec:install`. I've than modified my .rspec and rspec-helper files (using mocha and factory girl).

Than, I've generated the specs file for my model using `rails g rspec:model search`. My model is `search.rb` and class name is `Search`.

So in my `/spec/models/search_spec.rb` generated by rspec:model generator, I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Search do
  describe "#merge_searches" do

  end
end
```

But when I try to run the test, I get the error:

> Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:spec jan$ rspec models/search_spec.rb
>   /Users/jan/Documents/ruby/js3/spec/models/search_spec.rb:3:in `': uninitialized constant Search (NameError)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce that error if I don't have a model named Search. Once I create `app/models/search.rb` with content

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

the error goes away. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using MongoID, so my `app/models/search.rb` starts with just `class Search ...`

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out!

Comment: Actually I decided to give up. Im using MongoDB on this little project, and testing on it is hard (eg. factory girl won't work either). I guess this little site will be test-less for models. Only with unit testing on /lib stuff and capybara integration tests.